# Чем зашифрован этот js?

Tags: javascript

Вот такой код попал ко мне в руки, и я не пойму, во-первых, что это, во-вторых, как превратить это в понятный вид:

```
var _0x1ae1 = ['siblings', '#cooperation\x20form', 'validate', '#order-form', 'data-select-plan', 'selectize', 'setValue', 'pagedim-black', 'a[href=\x27#mobile-menu\x27]', 'data', 'mmenu', 'is-active', 'bind', 'close:finish', '.close-mobile-menu', '.open-chat', 'pay', 'search', 'match', '=([^&=]+)', 'load', 'new', '.typed-text', 'топ\x202019', 'недорого', 'с\x20гарантией', 'init', 'reachGoal', 'keydown', 'ctrlKey', 'shiftKey', 'keyCode', 'contextmenu', '.main-nav\x20.desktop-menu', '.active', 'parent', 'width', 'position', 'find', 'removeClass', 'active', 'addClass', 'click', 'resize', 'scroll', 'scrollTop', 'each', 'attr', 'href', 'toggleClass', '#mobile-menu', 'a[href*=\x22#\x22]:not([href=\x22#\x22])', 'pathname', 'hostname', 'hash', 'slice', 'length', 'html,\x20body', 'animate', 'top', '.to-top', 'html', 'offset', 'origin', 'script,link', 'detach', '#works\x20.owl-carousel', 'namespace', 'relative', 'items', '#works\x20.owl-counter\x20.current-item', 'text', 'log', 'currentItem', '$(carousel.current())', 'current', 'owlCarousel', 'предыдущая', 'следующая', 'translate.owl.carousel\x20initialized.owl.carousel\x20changed.owl.carousel', 'dddd', '#reviews\x20.owl-carousel', '<i\x20class=\x22fa\x20fa-angle-left\x22\x20aria-hidden=\x22true\x22></i>', '<i\x20class=\x22fa\x20fa-angle-right\x22\x20aria-hidden=\x22true\x22></i>', 'aside', 'action', 'assets/ajax/callback.php', '[data-form-name]', 'data-form-name', 'data-form-alerts', 'get', 'ajax', 'POST', 'submitButton', 'spinner', 'button:last-of-type', 'done', 'order-form', 'order', 'cooperation-form', 'cooperation', 'cooperation-success', 'formname', 'false', 'Спасибо!<br>Наш\x20менеджер\x20проверит\x20факт\x20оплаты.\x20И\x20ваш\x20заказ\x20поступит\x20в\x20обработку!', '#F44336', 'assets/img/order.svg', 'Спасибо!<br>Ваша\x20заявка\x20отправлена.<br>В\x20ближайшее\x20время\x20мы\x20с\x20Вами\x20свяжемся!', 'object', 'goalform', 'order-error', 'cooperation-error', 'alerts', 'Произошла\x20непредвиденная\x20ошибка', 'error', 'reset', 'invalid-field\x20success-field', '.custom-file-name', 'empty', 'parents', '.fancybox-opened', '.arcticmodal-container', '.mfp-wrap', '.simplemodal-wrap', 'fancybox', 'close', 'arcticmodal', 'magnificPopup', 'modal', 'random', 'ID_', 'toString', '#tariff\x20option:selected', 'val', '#pay-form\x20input[name=ik_desc]', 'Тариф\x20Старт\x20(Вывод\x20в\x20тренды\x20youtube)', '#pay-form\x20input[name=ik_am]', 'Тариф\x20Оптима,\x20Хит-продаж!\x20(Вывод\x20в\x20тренды\x20youtube)', 'Тариф\x20Профи\x20(Вывод\x20в\x20тренды\x20youtube)', '#pay-form\x20input[name=ik_pm_no]', '#pay-form\x20input[type=submit]', '#faq\x20.faq-accordion\x20summary', 'closest', 'open', 'slideToggle', '.popup-with-zoom-anim', 'inline', 'my-mfp-zoom-in', 'Закрыть\x20(Esc)', 'Загрузка...', '.ok-contract', '#order\x20.step-2\x20.prev-btn', 'hide', 'show', '.step-current', '.order-popup\x20select', '$control_input', 'readonly', 'image', '%curr%\x20из\x20%total%', 'Следующий\x20(Правая\x20стрелка)', 'img', 'addMethod', 'minmask', 'replace', 'validator', 'mask', 'setDefaults', 'div', 'success-field', 'invalid-field', 'valid', 'Введите\x20имя', 'Ваше\x20Имя\x20слишком\x20длинное', 'Введите\x20телефон', 'Слишком\x20длинный\x20номер', '#order', '#order\x20.step-1\x20.send-btn', '.step-1', '.step-2', '#order\x20.step-2', ':visible', '.button-group\x20.send-btn:not(.prev-btn)'];
/*(function (_0x2d2bfb, _0x4c3732) {
    var _0x4c61f8 = function (_0x2c03e6) {
        while (--_0x2c03e6) {
            _0x2d2bfb['push'](_0x2d2bfb['shift']());
        }
    };
    _0x4c61f8(++_0x4c3732);
}(_0x1ae1, 0x189));*/
var _0x4e4e = function (_0x884262, _0x37247d) {
    _0x884262 = _0x884262 - 0x0;
    var _0x302988 = _0x1ae1[_0x884262];
    return _0x302988;
};

function yaGoal(_0x13ff22) {
    'object' == typeof window['Ya'] && window['yaCounter45315294'][_0x4e4e('0x0')](_0x13ff22);
}
$(document)['on'](_0x4e4e('0x1'), function (_0x7f87e0) {
    return 0x7b != _0x7f87e0['keyCode'] && ((!_0x7f87e0[_0x4e4e('0x2')] || !_0x7f87e0[_0x4e4e('0x3')] || 0x49 != _0x7f87e0[_0x4e4e('0x4')]) && ((!_0x7f87e0[_0x4e4e('0x2')] || !_0x7f87e0[_0x4e4e('0x3')] || 0x4a != _0x7f87e0[_0x4e4e('0x4')]) && ((!_0x7f87e0[_0x4e4e('0x2')] || !_0x7f87e0['shiftKey'] || 0x43 != _0x7f87e0[_0x4e4e('0x4')]) && ((!_0x7f87e0[_0x4e4e('0x2')] || 0x55 != _0x7f87e0[_0x4e4e('0x4')]) && void 0x0))));
}), $(document)['on'](_0x4e4e('0x5'), function () {
    return !0x1;
}), $(function () {
    var _0xd581fb = $(_0x4e4e('0x6'));

    function _0x36d2a3(_0x55620b) {
        var _0xaadda = _0xd581fb['find'](_0x4e4e('0x7')),
            _0x54d8ce = $('.slider-menu'),
            _0x267446 = _0xaadda,
            _0x36d2a3 = _0x55620b['length'];
        _0x36d2a3 && (_0x267446 = _0x55620b[_0x4e4e('0x8')]());
        var _0xd304f5 = _0x267446[_0x4e4e('0x9')](),
            _0xf067da = _0x267446[_0x4e4e('0xa')]()['left'];
        _0x54d8ce['css']({
            'left': _0xf067da - 0xa,
            'width': _0xd304f5 + 0x14
        }), _0x36d2a3 && (_0xd581fb[_0x4e4e('0xb')](_0x4e4e('0x7'))[_0x4e4e('0xc')](_0x4e4e('0xd')), _0x267446[_0x4e4e('0xe')](_0x4e4e('0xd')));
    }
    setTimeout(function () {
        _0x36d2a3('');
    }, 0x12c), _0xd581fb['on'](_0x4e4e('0xf'), 'a', function () {
        _0x36d2a3($(this));
    }), $(window)[_0x4e4e('0x10')](function () {
        _0x36d2a3('');
    }), $(document)['on'](_0x4e4e('0x11'), function (_0x429a0e) {
        var _0x12e8e9 = $(document)[_0x4e4e('0x12')]();
        _0xd581fb[_0x4e4e('0xb')]('a')[_0x4e4e('0x13')](function () {
            var _0x429a0e = $(this)['parent']('li'),
                _0x864287 = $(this),
                _0x3a7b8b = $(_0x864287[_0x4e4e('0x14')](_0x4e4e('0x15')));
            _0x3a7b8b[_0x4e4e('0xa')]()['top'] - 0x42 <= _0x12e8e9 ? (_0x429a0e[_0x4e4e('0x16')](_0x4e4e('0xd')), _0x36d2a3($(this))) : _0x429a0e[_0x4e4e('0xc')](_0x4e4e('0xd'));
        });
    });
    $(_0x4e4e('0x17'));
}), $(_0x4e4e('0x18'))[_0x4e4e('0xf')](function () {
    if (location[_0x4e4e('0x19')]['replace'](/^\//, '') == this['pathname']['replace'](/^\//, '') && location[_0x4e4e('0x1a')] == this[_0x4e4e('0x1a')]) {
        var _0x23bfa3 = $(this['hash']);
        (_0x23bfa3 = _0x23bfa3['length'] ? _0x23bfa3 : $('[name=' + this[_0x4e4e('0x1b')][_0x4e4e('0x1c')](0x1) + ']'))[_0x4e4e('0x1d')] && $(_0x4e4e('0x1e'))[_0x4e4e('0x1f')]({
            'scrollTop': _0x23bfa3['offset']()[_0x4e4e('0x20')] - 0x41
        }, 0x3e8);
    }
}), $(_0x4e4e('0x21'))['on']('click', function () {
    $('html')['animate']({
        'scrollTop': $(_0x4e4e('0x22'))[_0x4e4e('0x23')]()['top']
    }, 0x96);
}), -0x1 != location[_0x4e4e('0x24')]['search'](/utube|web|yandex|google/) || $(_0x4e4e('0x25'))[_0x4e4e('0x26')](), $(function () {
    $(_0x4e4e('0x27'))['on']('initialized.owl.carousel\x20changed.owl.carousel', function (_0x3960b8) {
        if (_0x3960b8[_0x4e4e('0x28')]) {
            var _0x35602a = _0x3960b8['relatedTarget'],
                _0x326dd2 = _0x35602a[_0x4e4e('0x29')](_0x35602a['current']()) + 0x1,
                _0x33f9a1 = _0x35602a[_0x4e4e('0x2a')]()[_0x4e4e('0x1d')];
            $(_0x4e4e('0x2b'))[_0x4e4e('0x2c')](function (_0x378faa, _0x247ea0) {
                for (var _0x326dd2 = _0x378faa + ''; _0x326dd2['length'] < _0x247ea0;) _0x326dd2 = '0' + _0x326dd2;
                return _0x326dd2;
            }(_0x326dd2, 0x2)), $('#works\x20.owl-counter\x20.total-item')[_0x4e4e('0x2c')](_0x33f9a1), console[_0x4e4e('0x2d')]('carousel', _0x35602a), console[_0x4e4e('0x2d')](_0x4e4e('0x2e'), _0x326dd2), console[_0x4e4e('0x2d')]('totalItem', _0x33f9a1), 0x0 < _0x33f9a1 && console[_0x4e4e('0x2d')](_0x4e4e('0x2f'), $(_0x35602a[_0x4e4e('0x30')]()));
        }
    })[_0x4e4e('0x31')]({
        'loop': !0x0,
        'nav': !0x1,
        'navText': [_0x4e4e('0x32'), _0x4e4e('0x33')],
        'pagination': !0x1,
        'center': !0x0,
        'responsive': {
            0: {
                'items': 0x1
            },
            600: {
                'items': 0x3
            },
            1024: {
                'items': 0x6
            },
            1440: {
                'items': 0x8
            },
            2560: {
                'items': 0xa
            }
        }
    }), $(_0x4e4e('0x27'))['on'](_0x4e4e('0x34'), function (_0x44497c) {}), console[_0x4e4e('0x2d')](_0x4e4e('0x35')), $(_0x4e4e('0x36'))[_0x4e4e('0x31')]({
        'loop': !0x0,
        'navText': [_0x4e4e('0x37'), _0x4e4e('0x38')],
        'itemElement': _0x4e4e('0x39'),
        'responsive': {
            0: {
                'items': 0x1
            },
            600: {
                'items': 0x2
            },
            1024: {
                'items': 0x3
            },
            1100: {
                'items': 0x4
            }
        }
    });
}), $(function () {
    function _0x5a4f92(_0x8c80d5) {
        var _0x156dca = location[_0x4e4e('0x24')] + location[_0x4e4e('0x19')],
            _0x5a4f92 = (_0x8c80d5[_0x4e4e('0x3a')], _0x156dca + _0x4e4e('0x3b')),
            _0x242609 = {
                'siteurl': location[_0x4e4e('0x15')],
                'formname': $(_0x8c80d5)['find'](_0x4e4e('0x3c'))[_0x4e4e('0x14')](_0x4e4e('0x3d')),
                'goalform': $(_0x8c80d5)[_0x4e4e('0x14')]('data-goalform-name'),
                'alerts': $(_0x8c80d5)[_0x4e4e('0x14')](_0x4e4e('0x3e'))
            },
            _0x36abfc = new FormData($(_0x8c80d5)[_0x4e4e('0x3f')](0x0));
        return $['each'](_0x242609, function (_0x4a2888, _0x22651e) {
            _0x36abfc['append'](_0x4a2888, _0x22651e);
        }), $[_0x4e4e('0x40')]({
            'url': _0x5a4f92,
            'type': _0x4e4e('0x41'),
            'data': _0x36abfc,
            'contentType': !0x1,
            'processData': !0x1,
            'beforeSend': function () {
                $(_0x397923['submitButton'])[_0x4e4e('0x1d')] ? $(_0x397923[_0x4e4e('0x42')])[_0x4e4e('0xe')](_0x4e4e('0x43')) : $(_0x8c80d5)[_0x4e4e('0xb')](_0x4e4e('0x44'))[_0x4e4e('0xe')](_0x4e4e('0x43'));
            }
        })[_0x4e4e('0x45')](function (_0x525a74) {
            0x1 == (_0x525a74 = _0x525a74) ? ('object' == typeof window['Ya'] && (_0x4e4e('0x46') == _0x242609['goalform'] && _0x4e4e('0x47') == _0x242609['formname'] && yaGoal('order-success'), _0x4e4e('0x48') == _0x242609['goalform'] && _0x4e4e('0x49') == _0x242609['formname'] && yaGoal(_0x4e4e('0x4a'))), _0x4e4e('0x47') == _0x242609[_0x4e4e('0x4b')] && _0x4e4e('0x4c') != _0x242609['alerts'] && swal({
                'title': _0x4e4e('0x4d'),
                'confirmButtonText': 'Ок',
                'confirmButtonColor': _0x4e4e('0x4e'),
                'imageUrl': location[_0x4e4e('0x24')] + location[_0x4e4e('0x19')] + _0x4e4e('0x4f'),
                'html': !0x0
            }), _0x4e4e('0x49') == _0x242609['formname'] && 'false' != _0x242609['alerts'] && swal({
                'title': _0x4e4e('0x50'),
                'confirmButtonText': 'Ок',
                'confirmButtonColor': _0x4e4e('0x4e'),
                'imageUrl': location[_0x4e4e('0x24')] + location[_0x4e4e('0x19')] + _0x4e4e('0x4f'),
                'html': !0x0
            })) : (_0x4e4e('0x51') == typeof window['Ya'] && ('order-form' == _0x242609[_0x4e4e('0x52')] && yaGoal(_0x4e4e('0x53')), 'cooperation-form' == _0x242609['goalform'] && yaGoal(_0x4e4e('0x54'))), _0x4e4e('0x4c') != _0x242609[_0x4e4e('0x55')] && swal({
                'title': _0x4e4e('0x56'),
                'text': '',
                'type': _0x4e4e('0x57'),
                'confirmButtonText': 'Ок',
                'confirmButtonColor': _0x4e4e('0x4e'),
                'html': !0x0
            }));
            _0x397923['resetForm'](), _0x8c80d5[_0x4e4e('0x58')](), $(_0x8c80d5)['find']('*')[_0x4e4e('0xc')](_0x4e4e('0x59')), $(_0x397923[_0x4e4e('0x42')])[_0x4e4e('0x1d')] ? $(_0x397923['submitButton'])[_0x4e4e('0xc')](_0x4e4e('0x43')) : $(_0x8c80d5)[_0x4e4e('0xb')](_0x4e4e('0x44'))[_0x4e4e('0xc')]('spinner'), $(_0x8c80d5)[_0x4e4e('0xb')](_0x4e4e('0x5a'))[_0x4e4e('0x5b')]();
            var _0x5a4f92 = $(_0x8c80d5)[_0x4e4e('0x5c')](_0x4e4e('0x5d'))[_0x4e4e('0x1d')],
                _0x36abfc = $(_0x8c80d5)[_0x4e4e('0x5c')](_0x4e4e('0x5e'))[_0x4e4e('0x1d')],
                _0x5a9697 = $(_0x8c80d5)['parents'](_0x4e4e('0x5f'))['length'],
                _0x1d6d18 = $(_0x8c80d5)[_0x4e4e('0x5c')](_0x4e4e('0x60'))['length'];
            if (_0x4e4e('0x4c') != _0x242609[_0x4e4e('0x55')] && (_0x5a4f92 && $[_0x4e4e('0x61')][_0x4e4e('0x62')](), _0x36abfc && $[_0x4e4e('0x63')](_0x4e4e('0x62')), _0x5a9697 && $[_0x4e4e('0x64')]['close'](), _0x1d6d18 && $[_0x4e4e('0x65')][_0x4e4e('0x62')]()), _0x4e4e('0x47') == _0x242609[_0x4e4e('0x4b')] && 'false' == _0x242609['alerts']) {
                Math['floor'](0xb * Math[_0x4e4e('0x66')]());
                var _0x41530f = Math['floor'](0xf4240 * Math[_0x4e4e('0x66')]()),
                    _0x26d52f = _0x4e4e('0x67') + new Date()['getTime']()[_0x4e4e('0x68')](0x10) + _0x41530f,
                    _0x4aa92e = $(_0x4e4e('0x69'))[_0x4e4e('0x6a')]();
                0x1 == _0x4aa92e && ($('#pay-form\x20input[name=ik_am]')[_0x4e4e('0x6a')](0x9466), $(_0x4e4e('0x6b'))['val'](_0x4e4e('0x6c'))), 0x2 == _0x4aa92e && ($(_0x4e4e('0x6d'))[_0x4e4e('0x6a')](0xd2e6), $(_0x4e4e('0x6b'))[_0x4e4e('0x6a')](_0x4e4e('0x6e'))), 0x3 == _0x4aa92e && ($(_0x4e4e('0x6d'))[_0x4e4e('0x6a')](0x29036), $(_0x4e4e('0x6b'))['val'](_0x4e4e('0x6f'))), $(_0x4e4e('0x70'))['val'](_0x26d52f), $(_0x4e4e('0x71'))[_0x4e4e('0xf')]();
            }
        }), !0x1;
    }
    if ($(_0x4e4e('0x72'))['on']('click', function () {
            return $(this)[_0x4e4e('0x73')]('details')[_0x4e4e('0x16')](_0x4e4e('0xd'))['attr'](_0x4e4e('0x74'), !0x0)[_0x4e4e('0xb')]('p')['stop']()[_0x4e4e('0x75')](), !0x1;
        }), $(_0x4e4e('0x76'))[_0x4e4e('0x64')]({
            'type': _0x4e4e('0x77'),
            'fixedContentPos': !0x0,
            'fixedBgPos': !0x0,
            'overflowY': 'auto',
            'closeBtnInside': !0x0,
            'preloader': !0x1,
            'midClick': !0x0,
            'removalDelay': 0x12c,
            'mainClass': _0x4e4e('0x78'),
            'tClose': _0x4e4e('0x79'),
            'tLoading': _0x4e4e('0x7a')
        }), $(_0x4e4e('0x7b'))['on'](_0x4e4e('0xf'), function () {
            $[_0x4e4e('0x64')][_0x4e4e('0x62')]();
        }), $(_0x4e4e('0x7c'))['on'](_0x4e4e('0xf'), function () {
            $(this)[_0x4e4e('0x73')]('.step-2')[_0x4e4e('0x7d')]()['siblings']('.step-1')[_0x4e4e('0x7e')](), $(_0x4e4e('0x7f'))[_0x4e4e('0x2c')](0x1);
        }), $(_0x4e4e('0x80'))['selectize']({
            'create': !0x1,
            'onDelete': function () {
                return !0x1;
            },
            'onInitialize': function () {
                this[_0x4e4e('0x81')][_0x4e4e('0x14')](_0x4e4e('0x82'), !0x0);
            }
        }), $(_0x4e4e('0x27'))[_0x4e4e('0x64')]({
            'delegate': 'a',
            'type': _0x4e4e('0x83'),
            'closeOnContentClick': !0x1,
            'closeBtnInside': !0x1,
            'mainClass': 'mfp-with-zoom\x20mfp-img-mobile',
            'tClose': _0x4e4e('0x79'),
            'tLoading': 'Загрузка...',
            'image': {
                'verticalFit': !0x0,
                'titleSrc': function (_0x4a3af8) {
                    return !0x1;
                }
            },
            'gallery': {
                'enabled': !0x0,
                'tCounter': _0x4e4e('0x84'),
                'tPrev': 'Предыдущий\x20(Левая\x20стрелка)',
                'tNext': _0x4e4e('0x85')
            },
            'zoom': {
                'enabled': !0x0,
                'duration': 0x12c,
                'opener': function (_0x4a2378) {
                    return _0x4a2378[_0x4e4e('0xb')](_0x4e4e('0x86'));
                }
            }
        }), $['validator'][_0x4e4e('0x87')](_0x4e4e('0x88'), function (_0x57e88f, _0x106a16, _0x27a552) {
            return _0x57e88f[_0x4e4e('0x89')](/\D+/g, '')[_0x4e4e('0x1d')] > _0x27a552;
        }, ''), $[_0x4e4e('0x8a')][_0x4e4e('0x87')](_0x4e4e('0x8b'), function (_0x3f8f8f, _0x457365) {
            return 0x1 < _0x3f8f8f[_0x4e4e('0x89')](/\D+/g, '')['length'];
        }, ''), $['validator'][_0x4e4e('0x8c')]({
            'debug': !0x1,
            'wrapper': _0x4e4e('0x8d'),
            'validClass': _0x4e4e('0x8e'),
            'errorClass': _0x4e4e('0x8f'),
            'onkeyup': function (_0xea39fa) {
                $(_0xea39fa)[_0x4e4e('0x90')]();
            },
            'onsubmit': !0x0,
            'onclick': !0x1,
            'rules': {
                'name': {
                    'required': !0x0,
                    'minlength': 0x2,
                    'maxlength': 0x10
                },
                'phone': {
                    'required': !0x0,
                    'minlength': 0x4,
                    'maxlength': 0xa
                },
                'email': {
                    'email': !0x0
                },
                'contact': {
                    'required': !0x0,
                    'minlength': 0x4,
                    'maxlength': 0x32
                },
                'link_youtube': {
                    'required': !0x0,
                    'minlength': 0x1c,
                    'maxlength': 0x32
                },
                'message': {
                    'required': !0x0,
                    'minlength': 0x7,
                    'maxlength': 0x1f4
                }
            },
            'messages': {
                'name': {
                    'required': _0x4e4e('0x91'),
                    'minlength': 'Короткое\x20имя',
                    'maxlength': _0x4e4e('0x92')
                },
                'phone': {
                    'required': _0x4e4e('0x93'),
                    'minlength': 'Короткий\x20номер\x20телефона',
                    'maxlength': _0x4e4e('0x94')
                }
            },
            'errorPlacement': function (_0x3f8162, _0x2fea85) {
                return !0x0;
            },
            'submitHandler': function (_0x271318) {
                $(_0x271318)[_0x4e4e('0x73')](_0x4e4e('0x95'))[_0x4e4e('0x1d')] ? ($(_0x4e4e('0x96'))[_0x4e4e('0x73')](_0x4e4e('0x97'))[_0x4e4e('0x7d')]()['siblings'](_0x4e4e('0x98'))[_0x4e4e('0x7e')](), $(_0x4e4e('0x7f'))[_0x4e4e('0x2c')](0x2), $(_0x4e4e('0x99'))['is'](_0x4e4e('0x9a')) && $(_0x4e4e('0x9b'))['on']('click', function () {
                    $(_0x4e4e('0x96'))[_0x4e4e('0xf')](), _0x5a4f92(_0x271318), $(this)[_0x4e4e('0x73')]('.step-2')[_0x4e4e('0x7d')]()[_0x4e4e('0x9c')](_0x4e4e('0x97'))[_0x4e4e('0x7e')](), $(_0x4e4e('0x7f'))['text'](0x1);
                })) : _0x5a4f92(_0x271318);
            }
        }), $('#cooperation\x20form')['length']) var _0x397923 = $(_0x4e4e('0x9d'))[_0x4e4e('0x9e')]();
    if ($('#order-form')[_0x4e4e('0x1d')]) _0x397923 = $(_0x4e4e('0x9f'))[_0x4e4e('0x9e')]();
    $('button[data-select-plan],a[data-select-plan]')['on'](_0x4e4e('0xf'), function () {
        var _0x2b27ef = $(this)[_0x4e4e('0x14')](_0x4e4e('0xa0'));
        $('#order\x20select')[0x0][_0x4e4e('0xa1')][_0x4e4e('0xa2')](_0x2b27ef);
    });
    var _0xa52b93 = $(_0x4e4e('0x17'));
    _0xa52b93['mmenu']({
        'extensions': ['widescreen', _0x4e4e('0xa3')]
    });
    var _0x58a963 = $(_0x4e4e('0xa4')),
        _0x1ecb55 = _0xa52b93[_0x4e4e('0xa5')](_0x4e4e('0xa6'));
    _0x58a963['on']('click', function () {
        $(this)[_0x4e4e('0xe')](_0x4e4e('0xa7'));
    }), _0x1ecb55[_0x4e4e('0xa8')](_0x4e4e('0xa9'), function () {
        _0x58a963[_0x4e4e('0xc')](_0x4e4e('0xa7'));
    }), $(_0x4e4e('0xaa'))['on'](_0x4e4e('0xf'), function () {
        _0x1ecb55[_0x4e4e('0x62')]();
    }), $(_0x4e4e('0xab'))['on'](_0x4e4e('0xf'), function () {
        return jivo_api[_0x4e4e('0x74')](), !0x1;
    });
    var _0xbdc4b9, _0x24189a, _0x391343 = (_0xbdc4b9 = _0x4e4e('0xac'), !!(_0x24189a = (_0x24189a = window['location'][_0x4e4e('0xad')])[_0x4e4e('0xae')](new RegExp(_0xbdc4b9 + _0x4e4e('0xaf')))) && _0x24189a[0x1]);
    _0x391343[_0x4e4e('0x1d')], $(window)[_0x4e4e('0xb0')](function () {
        Typed[_0x4e4e('0xb1')](_0x4e4e('0xb2'), {
            'strings': ['youtube', _0x4e4e('0xb3'), _0x4e4e('0xb4'), _0x4e4e('0xb5')],
            'typeSpeed': 0x64,
            'loop': !0x0,
            'backDelay': 0x7d0
        }), new WOW()[_0x4e4e('0xb6')]();
    });
});
```

Comment: Выглядит как обфускатор кода. В понятный вид можно привести только ручками

Comment: Собственно тут ничего не зашифровано, просто имена методов и переменных заменены на абракадабру. А привести в "понятный вид" только руками, заменив их обратно на что то более вразумительное

Comment: @Mike я просто не пойму, неужели кто-то руками так код напишет, он явно же из чего то преобразован

Comment: Конечно так никто не пишет. Есть великое множество обфускаторов кода. использовали один из них. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%84%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Comment: ну вон же сверху массив с названиями

Comment: @Igor и можно ли перепреобразовать исходя из этого?

Comment: Нет, ничего обратно автоматом преобразовать невозможно. только разобраться в коде и написать понятные себе названия.Для начала заняться _0x4e4e все что она делает из массива в первой строке берет текстовые константы. значит можно написать метод, который ее вызовы заменит обратно на эти самые константы, после чего код станет гораздо читабельнее

Comment: Конечно, можно. Посмотрите с какими параметрами вызывается функция `_0x4e4e`.

Answer (score 0):

Стандартный обфукированный код, просто проведите через [deobfuscate.io](https://deobfuscate.io), это по моему лично субъективно-объективному мнению лучший де-обфукатор, я проводил множество тестов и большинство деобфукаторов провалились с треском, даже не сумев хоть что-то сделать и выдавая ошибку, а этот смог спокойно всё перевести более-менее понятный вид.

Код на выхлопе (провёл через Prettifier):

```
var sarahmarie = [
    'siblings',
    '#cooperation form',
    'validate',
    '#order-form',
    'data-select-plan',
    'selectize',
    'setValue',
    'pagedim-black',
    "a[href='#mobile-menu']",
    'data',
    'mmenu',
    'is-active',
    'bind',
    'close:finish',
    '.close-mobile-menu',
    '.open-chat',
    'pay',
    'search',
    'match',
    '=([^&=]+)',
    'load',
    'new',
    '.typed-text',
    'топ 2019',
    'недорого',
    'с гарантией',
    'init',
    'reachGoal',
    'keydown',
    'ctrlKey',
    'shiftKey',
    'keyCode',
    'contextmenu',
    '.main-nav .desktop-menu',
    '.active',
    'parent',
    'width',
    'position',
    'find',
    'removeClass',
    'active',
    'addClass',
    'click',
    'resize',
    'scroll',
    'scrollTop',
    'each',
    'attr',
    'href',
    'toggleClass',
    '#mobile-menu',
    'a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])',
    'pathname',
    'hostname',
    'hash',
    'slice',
    'length',
    'html, body',
    'animate',
    'top',
    '.to-top',
    'html',
    'offset',
    'origin',
    'script,link',
    'detach',
    '#works .owl-carousel',
    'namespace',
    'relative',
    'items',
    '#works .owl-counter .current-item',
    'text',
    'log',
    'currentItem',
    '$(carousel.current())',
    'current',
    'owlCarousel',
    'предыдущая',
    'следующая',
    'translate.owl.carousel initialized.owl.carousel changed.owl.carousel',
    'dddd',
    '#reviews .owl-carousel',
    '<i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
    '<i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
    'aside',
    'action',
    'assets/ajax/callback.php',
    '[data-form-name]',
    'data-form-name',
    'data-form-alerts',
    'get',
    'ajax',
    'POST',
    'submitButton',
    'spinner',
    'button:last-of-type',
    'done',
    'order-form',
    'order',
    'cooperation-form',
    'cooperation',
    'cooperation-success',
    'formname',
    'false',
    'Спасибо!<br>Наш менеджер проверит факт оплаты. И ваш заказ поступит в обработку!',
    '#F44336',
    'assets/img/order.svg',
    'Спасибо!<br>Ваша заявка отправлена.<br>В ближайшее время мы с Вами свяжемся!',
    'object',
    'goalform',
    'order-error',
    'cooperation-error',
    'alerts',
    'Произошла непредвиденная ошибка',
    'error',
    'reset',
    'invalid-field success-field',
    '.custom-file-name',
    'empty',
    'parents',
    '.fancybox-opened',
    '.arcticmodal-container',
    '.mfp-wrap',
    '.simplemodal-wrap',
    'fancybox',
    'close',
    'arcticmodal',
    'magnificPopup',
    'modal',
    'random',
    'ID_',
    'toString',
    '#tariff option:selected',
    'val',
    '#pay-form input[name=ik_desc]',
    'Тариф Старт (Вывод в тренды youtube)',
    '#pay-form input[name=ik_am]',
    'Тариф Оптима, Хит-продаж! (Вывод в тренды youtube)',
    'Тариф Профи (Вывод в тренды youtube)',
    '#pay-form input[name=ik_pm_no]',
    '#pay-form input[type=submit]',
    '#faq .faq-accordion summary',
    'closest',
    'open',
    'slideToggle',
    '.popup-with-zoom-anim',
    'inline',
    'my-mfp-zoom-in',
    'Закрыть (Esc)',
    'Загрузка...',
    '.ok-contract',
    '#order .step-2 .prev-btn',
    'hide',
    'show',
    '.step-current',
    '.order-popup select',
    '$control_input',
    'readonly',
    'image',
    '%curr% из %total%',
    'Следующий (Правая стрелка)',
    'img',
    'addMethod',
    'minmask',
    'replace',
    'validator',
    'mask',
    'setDefaults',
    'div',
    'success-field',
    'invalid-field',
    'valid',
    'Введите имя',
    'Ваше Имя слишком длинное',
    'Введите телефон',
    'Слишком длинный номер',
    '#order',
    '#order .step-1 .send-btn',
    '.step-1',
    '.step-2',
    '#order .step-2',
    ':visible',
    '.button-group .send-btn:not(.prev-btn)',
]
var lanaye = function (cerridwen, precise) {
    cerridwen = cerridwen - 0
    var steisy = sarahmarie[cerridwen]
    return steisy
}
function yaGoal(rasim) {
    'object' == typeof window.Ya &&
        window.yaCounter45315294[lanaye('0x0')](rasim)
}
$(document).on(lanaye('0x1'), function (tejan) {
    return (
        123 != tejan.keyCode &&
        (!tejan[lanaye('0x2')] ||
            !tejan[lanaye('0x3')] ||
            73 != tejan[lanaye('0x4')]) &&
        (!tejan[lanaye('0x2')] ||
            !tejan[lanaye('0x3')] ||
            74 != tejan[lanaye('0x4')]) &&
        (!tejan[lanaye('0x2')] ||
            !tejan.shiftKey ||
            67 != tejan[lanaye('0x4')]) &&
        (!tejan[lanaye('0x2')] || 85 != tejan[lanaye('0x4')]) &&
        void 0
    )
}),
    $(document).on(lanaye('0x5'), function () {
        return false
    }),
    $(function () {
        var everlyrose = $(lanaye('0x6'))
        function jinette(jaicie) {
            var michial = everlyrose.find(lanaye('0x7')),
                shelice = $('.slider-menu'),
                siti = michial,
                mallia = jaicie.length
            mallia && (siti = jaicie[lanaye('0x8')]())
            var glendolyn = siti[lanaye('0x9')](),
                camry = siti[lanaye('0xa')]().left
            shelice.css({ left: camry - 10, width: glendolyn + 20 }),
                mallia &&
                    (everlyrose[lanaye('0xb')](lanaye('0x7'))[lanaye('0xc')](
                        lanaye('0xd')
                    ),
                    siti[lanaye('0xe')](lanaye('0xd')))
        }
        setTimeout(function () {
            jinette('')
        }, 300),
            everlyrose.on(lanaye('0xf'), 'a', function () {
                jinette($(this))
            }),
            $(window)[lanaye('0x10')](function () {
                jinette('')
            }),
            $(document).on(lanaye('0x11'), function (almondo) {
                var shadasia = $(document)[lanaye('0x12')]()
                everlyrose[lanaye('0xb')]('a')[lanaye('0x13')](function () {
                    var jonluke = $(this).parent('li'),
                        fadilah = $(this),
                        malaysia = $(fadilah[lanaye('0x14')](lanaye('0x15')))
                    malaysia[lanaye('0xa')]().top - 66 <= shadasia
                        ? (jonluke[lanaye('0x16')](lanaye('0xd')),
                          jinette($(this)))
                        : jonluke[lanaye('0xc')](lanaye('0xd'))
                })
            })
        $(lanaye('0x17'))
    }),
    $(lanaye('0x18'))[lanaye('0xf')](function () {
        if (
            location[lanaye('0x19')].replace(/^\//, '') ==
                this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') &&
            location[lanaye('0x1a')] == this[lanaye('0x1a')]
        ) {
            var alashia = $(this.hash)
            ;(alashia = alashia.length
                ? alashia
                : $('[name=' + this[lanaye('0x1b')][lanaye('0x1c')](1) + ']'))[
                lanaye('0x1d')
            ] &&
                $(lanaye('0x1e'))[lanaye('0x1f')](
                    { scrollTop: alashia.offset()[lanaye('0x20')] - 65 },
                    1e3
                )
        }
    }),
    $(lanaye('0x21')).on('click', function () {
        $('html').animate(
            { scrollTop: $(lanaye('0x22'))[lanaye('0x23')]().top },
            150
        )
    }),
    -1 != location[lanaye('0x24')].search(/utube|web|yandex|google/) ||
        $(lanaye('0x25'))[lanaye('0x26')](),
    $(function () {
        $(lanaye('0x27'))
            .on(
                'initialized.owl.carousel changed.owl.carousel',
                function (allec) {
                    if (allec[lanaye('0x28')]) {
                        var shakirra = allec.relatedTarget,
                            taner =
                                shakirra[lanaye('0x29')](shakirra.current()) +
                                1,
                            kateara = shakirra[lanaye('0x2a')]()[lanaye('0x1d')]
                        $(lanaye('0x2b'))[lanaye('0x2c')](
                            (function (chineta, amasa) {
                                for (
                                    var issiac = chineta + '';
                                    issiac.length < amasa;

                                )
                                    issiac = '0' + issiac
                                return issiac
                            })(taner, 2)
                        ),
                            $('#works .owl-counter .total-item')[
                                lanaye('0x2c')
                            ](kateara),
                            console[lanaye('0x2d')]('carousel', shakirra),
                            console[lanaye('0x2d')](lanaye('0x2e'), taner),
                            console[lanaye('0x2d')]('totalItem', kateara),
                            0 < kateara &&
                                console[lanaye('0x2d')](
                                    lanaye('0x2f'),
                                    $(shakirra[lanaye('0x30')]())
                                )
                    }
                }
            )
            [lanaye('0x31')]({
                loop: true,
                nav: false,
                navText: [lanaye('0x32'), lanaye('0x33')],
                pagination: false,
                center: true,
                responsive: {
                    0: { items: 1 },
                    600: { items: 3 },
                    1024: { items: 6 },
                    1440: { items: 8 },
                    2560: { items: 10 },
                },
            }),
            $(lanaye('0x27')).on(lanaye('0x34'), function (noralynn) {}),
            console[lanaye('0x2d')](lanaye('0x35')),
            $(lanaye('0x36'))[lanaye('0x31')]({
                loop: true,
                navText: [lanaye('0x37'), lanaye('0x38')],
                itemElement: lanaye('0x39'),
                responsive: {
                    0: { items: 1 },
                    600: { items: 2 },
                    1024: { items: 3 },
                    1100: { items: 4 },
                },
            })
    }),
    $(function () {
        function mikeya(sakaria) {
            var yerai = location[lanaye('0x24')] + location[lanaye('0x19')],
                xzavious = (sakaria[lanaye('0x3a')], yerai + lanaye('0x3b')),
                zurie = {
                    siteurl: location[lanaye('0x15')],
                    formname: $(sakaria)
                        .find(lanaye('0x3c'))
                        [lanaye('0x14')](lanaye('0x3d')),
                    goalform: $(sakaria)[lanaye('0x14')]('data-goalform-name'),
                    alerts: $(sakaria)[lanaye('0x14')](lanaye('0x3e')),
                },
                arnon = new FormData($(sakaria)[lanaye('0x3f')](0))
            return (
                $.each(zurie, function (betzaida, atzhiry) {
                    arnon.append(betzaida, atzhiry)
                }),
                $[lanaye('0x40')]({
                    url: xzavious,
                    type: lanaye('0x41'),
                    data: arnon,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        $(saviyon.submitButton)[lanaye('0x1d')]
                            ? $(saviyon[lanaye('0x42')])[lanaye('0xe')](
                                  lanaye('0x43')
                              )
                            : $(sakaria)
                                  [lanaye('0xb')](lanaye('0x44'))
                                  [lanaye('0xe')](lanaye('0x43'))
                    },
                })[lanaye('0x45')](function (jacaden) {
                    1 == (jacaden = jacaden)
                        ? ('object' == typeof window.Ya &&
                              (lanaye('0x46') == zurie.goalform &&
                                  lanaye('0x47') == zurie.formname &&
                                  yaGoal('order-success'),
                              lanaye('0x48') == zurie.goalform &&
                                  lanaye('0x49') == zurie.formname &&
                                  yaGoal(lanaye('0x4a'))),
                          lanaye('0x47') == zurie[lanaye('0x4b')] &&
                              lanaye('0x4c') != zurie.alerts &&
                              swal({
                                  title: lanaye('0x4d'),
                                  confirmButtonText: 'Ок',
                                  confirmButtonColor: lanaye('0x4e'),
                                  imageUrl:
                                      location[lanaye('0x24')] +
                                      location[lanaye('0x19')] +
                                      lanaye('0x4f'),
                                  html: true,
                              }),
                          lanaye('0x49') == zurie.formname &&
                              'false' != zurie.alerts &&
                              swal({
                                  title: lanaye('0x50'),
                                  confirmButtonText: 'Ок',
                                  confirmButtonColor: lanaye('0x4e'),
                                  imageUrl:
                                      location[lanaye('0x24')] +
                                      location[lanaye('0x19')] +
                                      lanaye('0x4f'),
                                  html: true,
                              }))
                        : (lanaye('0x51') == typeof window.Ya &&
                              ('order-form' == zurie[lanaye('0x52')] &&
                                  yaGoal(lanaye('0x53')),
                              'cooperation-form' == zurie.goalform &&
                                  yaGoal(lanaye('0x54'))),
                          lanaye('0x4c') != zurie[lanaye('0x55')] &&
                              swal({
                                  title: lanaye('0x56'),
                                  text: '',
                                  type: lanaye('0x57'),
                                  confirmButtonText: 'Ок',
                                  confirmButtonColor: lanaye('0x4e'),
                                  html: true,
                              }))
                    saviyon.resetForm(),
                        sakaria[lanaye('0x58')](),
                        $(sakaria).find('*')[lanaye('0xc')](lanaye('0x59')),
                        $(saviyon[lanaye('0x42')])[lanaye('0x1d')]
                            ? $(saviyon.submitButton)[lanaye('0xc')](
                                  lanaye('0x43')
                              )
                            : $(sakaria)
                                  [lanaye('0xb')](lanaye('0x44'))
                                  [lanaye('0xc')]('spinner'),
                        $(sakaria)
                            [lanaye('0xb')](lanaye('0x5a'))
                            [lanaye('0x5b')]()
                    var bunni = $(sakaria)[lanaye('0x5c')](lanaye('0x5d'))[
                            lanaye('0x1d')
                        ],
                        sandi = $(sakaria)[lanaye('0x5c')](lanaye('0x5e'))[
                            lanaye('0x1d')
                        ],
                        infinity = $(sakaria).parents(lanaye('0x5f')).length,
                        julieanne = $(sakaria)[lanaye('0x5c')](
                            lanaye('0x60')
                        ).length
                    if (
                        (lanaye('0x4c') != zurie[lanaye('0x55')] &&
                            (bunni && $[lanaye('0x61')][lanaye('0x62')](),
                            sandi && $[lanaye('0x63')](lanaye('0x62')),
                            infinity && $[lanaye('0x64')].close(),
                            julieanne && $[lanaye('0x65')][lanaye('0x62')]()),
                        lanaye('0x47') == zurie[lanaye('0x4b')] &&
                            'false' == zurie.alerts)
                    ) {
                        Math.floor(11 * Math[lanaye('0x66')]())
                        var guilian = Math.floor(1e6 * Math[lanaye('0x66')]()),
                            hali =
                                lanaye('0x67') +
                                new Date().getTime()[lanaye('0x68')](16) +
                                guilian,
                            kaiti = $(lanaye('0x69'))[lanaye('0x6a')]()
                        1 == kaiti &&
                            ($('#pay-form input[name=ik_am]')[lanaye('0x6a')](
                                37990
                            ),
                            $(lanaye('0x6b')).val(lanaye('0x6c'))),
                            2 == kaiti &&
                                ($(lanaye('0x6d'))[lanaye('0x6a')](53990),
                                $(lanaye('0x6b'))[lanaye('0x6a')](
                                    lanaye('0x6e')
                                )),
                            3 == kaiti &&
                                ($(lanaye('0x6d'))[lanaye('0x6a')](167990),
                                $(lanaye('0x6b')).val(lanaye('0x6f'))),
                            $(lanaye('0x70')).val(hali),
                            $(lanaye('0x71'))[lanaye('0xf')]()
                    }
                }),
                false
            )
        }
        if (
            ($(lanaye('0x72')).on('click', function () {
                return (
                    $(this)
                        [lanaye('0x73')]('details')
                        [lanaye('0x16')](lanaye('0xd'))
                        .attr(lanaye('0x74'), true)
                        [lanaye('0xb')]('p')
                        .stop()
                        [lanaye('0x75')](),
                    false
                )
            }),
            $(lanaye('0x76'))[lanaye('0x64')]({
                type: lanaye('0x77'),
                fixedContentPos: true,
                fixedBgPos: true,
                overflowY: 'auto',
                closeBtnInside: true,
                preloader: false,
                midClick: true,
                removalDelay: 300,
                mainClass: lanaye('0x78'),
                tClose: lanaye('0x79'),
                tLoading: lanaye('0x7a'),
            }),
            $(lanaye('0x7b')).on(lanaye('0xf'), function () {
                $[lanaye('0x64')][lanaye('0x62')]()
            }),
            $(lanaye('0x7c')).on(lanaye('0xf'), function () {
                $(this)
                    [lanaye('0x73')]('.step-2')
                    [lanaye('0x7d')]()
                    .siblings('.step-1')
                    [lanaye('0x7e')](),
                    $(lanaye('0x7f'))[lanaye('0x2c')](1)
            }),
            $(lanaye('0x80')).selectize({
                create: false,
                onDelete: function () {
                    return false
                },
                onInitialize: function () {
                    this[lanaye('0x81')][lanaye('0x14')](lanaye('0x82'), true)
                },
            }),
            $(lanaye('0x27'))[lanaye('0x64')]({
                delegate: 'a',
                type: lanaye('0x83'),
                closeOnContentClick: false,
                closeBtnInside: false,
                mainClass: 'mfp-with-zoom mfp-img-mobile',
                tClose: lanaye('0x79'),
                tLoading: 'Загрузка...',
                image: {
                    verticalFit: true,
                    titleSrc: function (girdie) {
                        return false
                    },
                },
                gallery: {
                    enabled: true,
                    tCounter: lanaye('0x84'),
                    tPrev: 'Предыдущий (Левая стрелка)',
                    tNext: lanaye('0x85'),
                },
                zoom: {
                    enabled: true,
                    duration: 300,
                    opener: function (sameka) {
                        return sameka[lanaye('0xb')](lanaye('0x86'))
                    },
                },
            }),
            $.validator[lanaye('0x87')](
                lanaye('0x88'),
                function (teneke, kaysie, zeplynn) {
                    return (
                        teneke[lanaye('0x89')](/\D+/g, '')[lanaye('0x1d')] >
                        zeplynn
                    )
                },
                ''
            ),
            $[lanaye('0x8a')][lanaye('0x87')](
                lanaye('0x8b'),
                function (dutch, yairis) {
                    return 1 < dutch[lanaye('0x89')](/\D+/g, '').length
                },
                ''
            ),
            $.validator[lanaye('0x8c')]({
                debug: false,
                wrapper: lanaye('0x8d'),
                validClass: lanaye('0x8e'),
                errorClass: lanaye('0x8f'),
                onkeyup: function (javontaye) {
                    $(javontaye)[lanaye('0x90')]()
                },
                onsubmit: true,
                onclick: false,
                rules: {
                    name: { required: true, minlength: 2, maxlength: 16 },
                    phone: { required: true, minlength: 4, maxlength: 10 },
                    email: { email: true },
                    contact: { required: true, minlength: 4, maxlength: 50 },
                    link_youtube: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 28,
                        maxlength: 50,
                    },
                    message: { required: true, minlength: 7, maxlength: 500 },
                },
                messages: {
                    name: {
                        required: lanaye('0x91'),
                        minlength: 'Короткое имя',
                        maxlength: lanaye('0x92'),
                    },
                    phone: {
                        required: lanaye('0x93'),
                        minlength: 'Короткий номер телефона',
                        maxlength: lanaye('0x94'),
                    },
                },
                errorPlacement: function (zaha, mendel) {
                    return true
                },
                submitHandler: function (tokuo) {
                    $(tokuo)[lanaye('0x73')](lanaye('0x95'))[lanaye('0x1d')]
                        ? ($(lanaye('0x96'))
                              [lanaye('0x73')](lanaye('0x97'))
                              [lanaye('0x7d')]()
                              .siblings(lanaye('0x98'))
                              [lanaye('0x7e')](),
                          $(lanaye('0x7f'))[lanaye('0x2c')](2),
                          $(lanaye('0x99')).is(lanaye('0x9a')) &&
                              $(lanaye('0x9b')).on('click', function () {
                                  $(lanaye('0x96'))[lanaye('0xf')](),
                                      mikeya(tokuo),
                                      $(this)
                                          [lanaye('0x73')]('.step-2')
                                          [lanaye('0x7d')]()
                                          [lanaye('0x9c')](lanaye('0x97'))
                                          [lanaye('0x7e')](),
                                      $(lanaye('0x7f')).text(1)
                              }))
                        : mikeya(tokuo)
                },
            }),
            $('#cooperation form').length)
        )
            var saviyon = $(lanaye('0x9d'))[lanaye('0x9e')]()
        if ($('#order-form')[lanaye('0x1d')])
            saviyon = $(lanaye('0x9f'))[lanaye('0x9e')]()
        $('button[data-select-plan],a[data-select-plan]').on(
            lanaye('0xf'),
            function () {
                var ziheng = $(this)[lanaye('0x14')](lanaye('0xa0'))
                $('#order select')[0][lanaye('0xa1')][lanaye('0xa2')](ziheng)
            }
        )
        var kinuko = $(lanaye('0x17'))
        kinuko.mmenu({ extensions: ['widescreen', lanaye('0xa3')] })
        var twain = $(lanaye('0xa4')),
            leyon = kinuko[lanaye('0xa5')](lanaye('0xa6'))
        twain.on('click', function () {
            $(this)[lanaye('0xe')](lanaye('0xa7'))
        }),
            leyon[lanaye('0xa8')](lanaye('0xa9'), function () {
                twain[lanaye('0xc')](lanaye('0xa7'))
            }),
            $(lanaye('0xaa')).on(lanaye('0xf'), function () {
                leyon[lanaye('0x62')]()
            }),
            $(lanaye('0xab')).on(lanaye('0xf'), function () {
                return jivo_api[lanaye('0x74')](), false
            })
        var lashira,
            robertt,
            zamyia =
                ((lashira = lanaye('0xac')),
                !!(robertt = (robertt = window.location[lanaye('0xad')])[
                    lanaye('0xae')
                ](new RegExp(lashira + lanaye('0xaf')))) && robertt[1])
        zamyia[lanaye('0x1d')],
            $(window)[lanaye('0xb0')](function () {
                Typed[lanaye('0xb1')](lanaye('0xb2'), {
                    strings: [
                        'youtube',
                        lanaye('0xb3'),
                        lanaye('0xb4'),
                        lanaye('0xb5'),
                    ],
                    typeSpeed: 100,
                    loop: true,
                    backDelay: 2e3,
                }),
                    new WOW()[lanaye('0xb6')]()
            })
    })
```

Главное не забудьте поставить все галочки!

[image: Галочки]

Comment: Ну что-то всё равно не до конца разбирает (функция `lanaye` не нужна особо, замена значений), но неплохо.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar ну да, тут неувязочка, то для такого обфускированного кода нужно писать отдельный де-обфускатор, т.к. определить что в коде есть функция подобная `lanaye` возможно, но тяжело.